# ServiceStack and Kestrel: Using the .Map function to route to ServiceStack instances based on path (middleware)?

Tags: .net-core, servicestack, kestrel

We are looking into .NET Core and Kestrel and using ServiceStack.

It's easy to add servicestack, using the Extensionmethod:

```
app.UseServiceStack(new AppHost { 
    AppSettings = new NetCoreAppSettings(Configuration) 
});
```

However, we are looking into starting several different AppHostBase implementations (so we get the option to handle things differently), but they all share the same webserver, port etc, since Kestrel is the base.

The idea is then that Kestrel should route incoming http requests to the correct AppHostBase, and the use of [.Map (middleware)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-2.2) sounded like a nice way to do it:

```
app.Map("/map2", HandleMapTest2);
```

However, I'm not sure how to achieve that using Servicestack. There is no ext method for Map in Servicestack, and using the .Map function above takes second parameter as `Action<IApplicationBuilder>`.

I have looked at [the source code](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/AppHostBase.NetCore.cs) and I see that AppHostBase.Bind(IApplicationBuilder) will eventually do a `app.Use(...)` which isn't what we want.

So, how can I use the Map function and route requests to different AppHostBase implementations?

### Update

Mythz says only one instance of ServiceStack is possible. But how can I then use Map to route specific sub-paths to the one ServiceStack instance, for example "/ss" goes to the SS instance, but something else goes elsewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, we are looking into starting several different AppHostBase
>   implementations

You can't have multiple ServiceStack's AppHost's, there can only be 1 singleton instance within a .NET Core process.

If your Service Implementations are in different Assemblies you can [register them with your AppHost Contructor](https://docs.servicestack.net/modularizing-services).

The way to configure ServiceStack to run on a different path is to set `Config.HandlerFactoryPath`, e.g:

```
SetConfig(new HostConfig {
    HandlerFactoryPath = "/map2"
})
```

Comment: Yeah, I remember you saying that in other posts. That is too bad, since it would be a great feature to be able to start several of those, and then one could start one for each "module", and that module could define its on PreRequestFilters, GlobalFilters and other things.

Comment: So, lets assume I only start _one_ ServiceStack instance, but I want a Map anyways, so path "/ss" routes to ServiceStack instance, while other things can route differently. How would I do that then?

Comment: @Ted that's what my answer, answers.

Comment: Well, shouldnt that be configured before ServiceStack, in the Startup.cs (Kestrel) part? That code you provided is inside ServiceStack, right?

Comment: @Ted That’s how it’s always been done in ServiceStack, the same way in all it’s supported hosts/platforms.

Comment: Right, but somehow, before SS, Kestrel determines where it routes a request. Since Kestrel has that .Map option, it should be possible to use it, not putting that code inside SS. Otherwise, you'll have some royting in the Kestrel part, and some inside the SS part.
 You're saying its not possible to have it all outside of SS?

Comment: @Ted ASP.NET Core requests are handled by an App's registered modules, in the order they're registered, when a module doesn't handle a request it's passed to the next module to handle, and what happens when ServiceStack is configured to handle a path, it doesn't handle requests outside the path, which is handled by the next registered module.

Comment: ok, thanks for the answers. I guess the .Map method in Kestrel cannot be used with SS then =)